# make turn on/off or deauthorized user from my app, and list action of user from app

Tags: javascript, facebook

I submitting an app to Facebook with open graph news read type by javascript.
All done so well with flow from user asking for authorized my app, and show the button help user can public the article then they can remove if they want to.

Today I got the request from Facebook need to change my app:

> requirements
>   (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#read).
>   Please make sure your users can (1) Turn sharing on/off globally on
>   each page an article appears. (2) Remove articles they shared within
>   your app on each page an article appears. (3) Only generate read
>   actions when you're sure someone is interested in reading the article
>   - only publish after 10 seconds.

The third request is easy just use timeout to show the button submit after user read article.

The seconds is so hard because I don't know how to full the array list of pass action of user doing with my app include action id and title of article they post which I can use to create "remove link" for each of them if user want to.

The fist request I did search for method of javascript to de-authorized the app from user (not revoke permission) so I can ask user to be reauthorized if they need.

Please help.

Beside I see very nice 2 sample in guild page

```
https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/OG_App_PublishToggle.png
https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/OG_App_DeleteActivity.png
```

But they din't give out the link of live site using it.
or may be that is one of Facebook markup similar "recommend box" , but how/where we can get it?

Please advices for the script or sample as Facebook dose will be help full
regards

**UPDATE 1** I found the way to reauthorized all app or revoke one permission.
here the function:

```
var permsNeededPub = "publish_stream";
///notice that if permission is "publish_actions" revoke function not work
function xlfb_revokePerm() {
        FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete",{permission:permsNeededPub}, function(response){
            console.log(response);      
            if(response){
                console.log(' Remove success '+permsNeededPub);
            }
        });

}

function xlfb_removeApp() {
    FB.api("/me/permissions", "delete", function(response){
        console.log("User removed the app from acount: "+response);                                  
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

> The seconds is so hard because I don't know how to full the array list of pass action of user doing with my app include action id and title of article they post which I can use to create "remove link" for each of them if user want to.

Whenever a user takes an OG action on your site - save the action_instance_id you are getting back from the API call and whatever extra data you might need to your database.

> The fist request I did search for method of javascript to de-authorized the app from user (not revoke permission) so I can ask user to be reauthorized if they need.

Why would you want to de-authorize the app?

All that’s required here is to have a global on/off switch for all sharing activity – so if the user sets it to *off*, then you just don’t publish any actions for him as long as he leaves this setting set to *off*.